# Мозилла и событие onkeypress

Tags: javascript, firefox

Ребята, что делать? Есть функция, которая привязана к обработчику события **`onkeypress`** . Проверяет на валидность нажимаемые кнопки. Так вот в хроме и опере эта проверка пропускает функциональные кнопки (backspace, вперед, назад). В Мозилле же такие нажатия почему-то возвращают `false`. То бишь вводимый текст нельзя редактировать. В чем дело?

```
function validateKeyPressInput(e){
 e = e || window.event; 
 var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
 var char = String.fromCharCode(code);
 var t = char.match(/[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9_-]/);
 if (t) return true;
 return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавь фильтр по коду для системных клавиш. Что-то типа:

```
function validateKeyPressInput(e){
 e = e || window.event; 
 var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
 if(code == 8 || code == 37 || code == 39 || code == 46)
 //бэкспейс, стрелки, делит. добавь, что еще нужно
   return true;
 var char = String.fromCharCode(code);
 var t = char.match(/[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9_-]/);
 if (t) return true;
 return false;
}
```

Comment: @burashka-lcme, круто. Может быть, так везде и делается, только непонятно, почему хром и опера понимают все без этих дополнительных проверок...

Comment: Со специфическими кнопками onkeypress работает в разных браузерах по разному. Это известная вещь и принято использовать onkeydown.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp

Comment: @burashka-lcme, onkeydown решает эту проблему опять же  в хроме и опере, мозилла стоит на своем.

Comment: @burashka-lcme, ответ ваш отмечу как правильный. Нужно просто самому углубиться в документацию. Жаль, что в наш-то век война браузеров продолжается. Меня вообще сегодня опера взбесила - span с float:right ну никак не хочет находиться там, где ему нужно. Хотя все остальные браузеры нормально фунциклируют.))

Comment: @burashka-lcme, ваш код тоже не работает, пропускает символы на верхнего ряда !"№;%:?*().